# Laravel Scheduling cron job on host

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-5, cpanel

I have some task and my host is Cpanel. When I try to add this command have an error .

[image]

Comment: Remove `*` from the command field and obviously replace `/path/to/artisan` with the actual path too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading asterisks in command field. Cpanel will add them internally from inputs above.

So, the command input should only contain

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And as @Ben Swinburne correctly mentioned in his comment:

> and obviously replace /path/to/artisan with the actual path too.

Comment: Would you say I add command name of laravel console ? and where i add this 
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @MortezaNegahi, @Finwe says that you should only add `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` as cron command when adding through CPanel